# Aardvark .dll file using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to write a script in C# using visual studio and the Total Phase Aardvark API package however when I try to add a reference to the .dll file I get the error, "a reference to aardvark.dll could not be added. Please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component. Note that

The API comes with two .net files, aardvark.dll and aardvark_net.dll. It seems like aardvark.dll is the one that is causing the error. I have already tried many fixes including adding these files to the environmental variables path and putting them in the project directory which have not worked to my knowledge.

Comment: Given the library names, I would wager that you should be referencing the "_net.dll".

Comment: I did reference the _net.dll to my knowledge but the aardvark.dll file still needs to be used and referencing it does not work.

Comment: Alright, what happens when you reference the "_net.dll" and make sure both libraries are in your output directory?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't download the libraries without creating a user account to download the software, this is partially conjecture.

Given that there are two DLLs, and that one of them is tagged with '_net', and that the library purports to have bindings for multiple languages, the most likely case is that you have one native library ('aardvark.dll') and one .NET assembly ('aardvark_net.dll'). You cannot directly reference a native library in the way you would do with a .NET assembly.

You can confim this by attempting to load the two libraries in a tool like ILSpy. The .NET assembly should load correctly and show you the contained classes, while the native assembly will fail to load.

To get this working in your project try the following:

- Add a reference to the 'aardvark_net.dll'
- Add 'aardvark.dll' to your project as a file, not a reference, and configure it to copy to the output folder on build.

(It's fairly common practice to use a wrapper that invokes methods in the native DLL rather than rewriting the entire library in C# or VB.NET.)

Comment: When I do this the solution builds with warning about conflicting types between the _net.dll and the aardvark.cs file that the API also uses. When I run the solution I now get, "System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'TotalPhase.AardvarkApi' threw an exception.'"

Comment: Not much else I can do since I have no access to the files in question. You're going to have to dig through the help and forums on their site.